# Applicative that increments the environment in haskell

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm wondering if there is an `Applicative` that can track how many applicative operations have occurred. I tried to implement it as follows:

```
import Control.Applicative

main :: IO ()
main = print $ run 1 $ (,,,) <$> FromInt id <*> FromInt id <*> FromInt id <*> FromInt id

data FromInt a = FromInt (Int -> a)

run :: Int -> FromInt a -> a
run i (FromInt f) = f i

instance Functor FromInt where
  fmap g (FromInt f) = FromInt (g . f)

instance Applicative FromInt where
  pure a = FromInt (const a)
  FromInt f <*> FromInt g = FromInt (\i -> f i (g (i + 1)))
```

But, this of course does not work. If we call runhaskell on the file, we get this:

```
(1,2,2,2)
```

And what I want is this:

```
(1,2,3,4)
```

I've seen people accomplish this effect by pushing the requirement to increment into the actual data (this is how yesod-forms does its formlet-style implementation). This more-or-less uses a variation on `State`, and it allows people to break assumed invariants if they don't use particular helper functions (I think the yesod one is called `mhelper`). I want to know if the incrementing can be pulled into the applicative instance as I have tried to do. This would make violating this particular invariant impossible.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible because applicative actions can not depend on a previous result.  To do this I think you have to have a monad to get the output you want.

Comment: You don't need monads. The applicative instance for `State` works fine, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`(,) a` is an `Applicative` when `a` is a `Monoid`. We can compose `(,) (Sum Int)` with other applicative using `Data.Functor.Compose`, and get an applicative that lets us estimate the "cost" assigned to a computation before running it.

To count the steps, we need a lift function from the base applicative that always assigns a cost of 1:

```
module Main where

import Data.Monoid
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Functor.Compose

type CountedIO a = Compose ((,) (Sum Int)) IO a

-- lift from IO
step :: IO a -> CountedIO a
step cmd = Compose (Sum 1, cmd)

countSteps :: CountedIO a -> Int
countSteps = getSum . fst . getCompose

exec :: CountedIO a -> IO a
exec =  snd . getCompose

program :: CountedIO () 
program = step (putStrLn "aaa") *>  step (putStrLn "bbb") *> step (putStrLn "ccc")

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ "Number of steps: " ++ show (countSteps program)
    exec program
```

For greater safety, we could hide the composed aplicative behind a newtype, and not export the constructor, only the `step` function.

(Actions created with `pure` have cost 0 and do not count as a step.)

Comment: This is a good solution, but it is ultimately the thing that I'm trying to avoid doing. I will wait a while and accept this if no one can come up with a better way (one that doesn't require hiding the data constructor to preserve the invariant).

Comment: @Andrew Thaddeus Martin I think it will be difficult to pull the invariant into the Applicative while preserving Applicative laws. If `(<*>)` always increments the count, what to make of the law `pure id <*> v = v` ?

Comment: You are correct. The instance I am looking for is provably impossible. Thanks.